# How to disable button in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I try to disable a button when the user doesn't have rights.

I have this:

```
if (Html.Gebruiker().Autorisatie.SelfserviceHeeftBetermeldenKnop)
{
    if (VerzuimKanBeterMelden)
    {
        <a id="aanmaken" class="btn btn-warning k-button-icontext " href="@Url.Action("VerzuimMelding", "Verzuim", new { area = "ESS" })" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px">beter melden</a>
    }
    else
    {
        <a id="aanmaken" class="btn btn-warning k-button-icontext hidden" href="#" title="Op dit moment kun je je niet beter melden" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px">eter melden</a>
    }
}
```

But when the user doesnt has rights the button is still visible.

Comment: what do you see the value of "VerzuimKanBeterMelden" when you debug this code?

Comment: The title is totally misleading, there is no such thing as a button in asp.net mvc, this is not a button (technically, it's a html link/anchor) and also technically it's not being disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change attribute of a tag named disabled like this :

```
if (Html.Gebruiker().Autorisatie.SelfserviceHeeftBetermeldenKnop)
{
    if (VerzuimKanBeterMelden)
    {
        <a id="aanmaken" class="btn btn-warning k-button-icontext " href="@Url.Action("VerzuimMelding", "Verzuim", new { area = "ESS" })" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px">beter melden</a>
    }
    else
    {
        <a id="aanmaken" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-warning k-button-icontext" href="#" title="Op dit moment kun je je niet beter melden" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px">eter melden</a>
    }
}
```

if not working check the value of VerzuimKanBeterMelden property